# How to switch workspace with mouse wheel in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I had this feature in 11.10 after using a tweak by Ubuntu tweak. The new version for 12.04 seems not to have this tweak. How can I get this tweak?

Comment: This only seems to work when you are over the desktop. IF you have your mouse pointer in a window it does nothing. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve that with CompizConfig Settings Manager.

**Install CompizConfig Settings Manager:**

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Or search for "compizconfig-settings-manager" in Software Center and install it from there.

**How to set it up?**

- Once installed, Hit Super key (Windows key) to open Unity dash and search for "ccsm" and open it.
- Navigate to Desktop > Viewport Swicher

[image]

- Goto "Desktop-based Viewport Switching"
- Enable and set "Move Next" to button 5, And "Move Prev" to button 4.

[image]

That's It!

Comment: Doesn't work in 15.04.

Comment: Doesn't work in 16.04. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04, and I found a better way (at least for me) than the `Move Next` / `Move Prev` described by Basharat Sialvi, still using the CompizConfig Settings Manager that he suggested: in the `Desktop Wall` page, in the tab `Edge Flipping`, enable `Edge Flip Pointer` to switch to the next viewport.

Answer (score 0):

So far, after having the same problem with 11.10 upgrade to 12.04, that this feature was unavailable.

What I tried was

```
unity --reset
```

in a terminal window. This added the scroll wheel to the viewport switcher.

Afterwards, this still did not work fully for me, but it's worth a shot.