# Can I switch between workspaces with middle click?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I seem to remember that there was a way to hold down the middle mouse button and have it bring up the workplace switcher, then twitch the mouse in the direction of the workspace you wanted.

The UI when the middle button was clicked was identical to the way Precise now performs CTRL+SHIFT+arrow moves, but using the mouse is quicker.  Is this still possible in Precise?

Comment: Its CTRL+ALT+Arrow for precise and identical question with answer  here http://askubuntu.com/q/137058/71679

Comment: i voted it as duplicate, but it's not exactly the same.  wheel is a more logical option as it allows you to go back and forward.  you want desktop cube if you want a single button to move to the right

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do it using the mouse middle button.
The mouse middle button in Ubuntu 12.04 is used to switch between open applications.
Applications such as compiz might give you the ability to accomplish this.