# Are there any risks to using CCSM in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, ccsm

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit. What is the official, latest position on using CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) under this version of Ubuntu? I've seen conflicting answers and comments here, some [suggesting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137058/how-to-switch-workspace-via-mouse-wheel-in-12-04) installing CCSM, others reporting that it is not supported and [could](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/101415#101415) [break](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) Unity. I'm missing a few features/settings, which I'd like to change, but not at the risk of breaking a new install.

Comment: I did link to that in my question. The question and answers are from more than a year ago (November 2011).

Comment: The answers on the other question are still pretty much relevant. CCSM is a powerful tool but has its own drawbacks. I am going to have to close this one as duplicate of the other one.

Comment: So can I safely install it and use it, or is it going to break my system?

Comment: @SabreWolfy Sure, you can install and use it. I can also tell it has a good chance of breaking your system. Use with much care.