# How to switch workspace with mouse wheel with Compiz

Tags: 16.04, compiz, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I've just upgraded from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. I am using Compiz as window manager. Unfortunately I am no longer able to use the mouse wheel on the workspace pane (bottom right on screen) to scroll forward/backward between the workspaces.

I have CompizConfig Settings Manager installed, but cannot find such a setting in it. Is there a way to enable this feature again?

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+ALT+ARROW KEY and CTRL+ALT+MOUSE WHEEL?

Comment: @VinuKevy: Ctrl+Alt+Arrow-Key is working. Ctrl+Alt+Mouse-Wheel is not doing anything.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly You should place your cursor over a window tray before using Ctrl+Alt+Mouse Wheel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch workspace with mouse wheel in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137058/how-to-switch-workspace-with-mouse-wheel-in-unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong window manager after the update to Ubutnu 16.04 LTS. In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I was using Metacity which has this feature of switching workspaces with the mouse wheel by default. So I simply switched from Compiz back to Metacity.

Answer (score 3):

To do so (presuming you have `compizconfig-settings-manager` installed)

Go to Desktop > Viewport Switcher.

[image]

It shows 20 buttons by default, which doesn't mean you actually can trigger 20 buttons.

To check which ones work, you can use the `xev` command. Type the command into a terminal, ensure the `xev` window has focus and then try your buttons.

[image]

Comment: Well it does seem to work with "button 4" and "button 5", but only if no program has the focus. For example if I have a firefox window open, it scrolls the page up/down instead of switching the workspace. I also tried it with some combinations (ctrl, shift, alt or super). But it is the same. Any ideas?